# Change the version manually of a Document in Alfresco using OpenCmis

Tags: java, alfresco, opencmis

I want to know how can we change the Document Version Manually in Alfresco using OpenCmis? As of now when i update the document, every time alfresco change the version itself but I want to change version from user input like 1.0,2.0, 2.1 etc.

For Eg. document.txt 1.0,
        document.txt 1.1

Instead of document.txt 1.1 i want to place version 2.3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no way to accomplish your goal under CMIS. The [spec](http://docs.oasis-open.org/cmis/CMIS/v1.0/errata-01/os/cmis-spec-v1.0-errata-01-os-complete.html#_Toc243905396) mandates all versioning properties on a `cmis:document` to be read only, and the only way to affect them in some ways is through the Versioning API, which only allow you to specify whether you're creating a minor or a major version, and an optional checkin comment.

You will need to write some more sophisticated server side extension to Alfresco if you want to do that, or extend your content model to provide a custom property to hold the information you currently want to store into the version label.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it through code [example 1](http://forums.alfresco.com/forum/developer-discussions/other-apis/issue-programmatic-versioning-manually-uploaded-file-11062010) [example 2](http://forums.alfresco.com/forum/developer-discussions/repository-services/change-old-version-properties-document-12212012-0937)

or

You can do it through db update [example](http://forums.alfresco.com/forum/developer-discussions/repository-services/change-old-version-properties-document-12212012-0937)

explore more [options](https://www.google.co.in/search?q=code+to+change+alfresco+document+version) if above doesnt meet your requierement.

Comment: yes I had but couldn't get success... I had update the property with versionLabel but still Alfresco do same...

Comment: have you tried `cm:versionable` to `false` ? or do you need it to be versionable ?

Comment: yes I had tried that... but I couldn't change the Major version manually or user input..

Comment: the db update link is not as described and will not work