# How can I change the version of each file in the postgres DB?

Tags: alfresco

I have uploaded some files to a new installation of alfresco, but I want to modify the version of teh files as they are not 1.0.

Which table should I modify in order to change the version?

Thanks!

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to use the Alfresco Version Service API to make the changes, rather than messing around in the database?

Comment: I'm quite new with alfresco and don't really know which is the best way to do that. I've looking in the Alfresco Version Service API and I don't see any function to set the version.. How should I do that?

Comment: If you're new to Alfresco then you really shouldn't be going anywhere near the low-level database, that's very much advanced developers only! Do you want to set the same different version on every document, or a different one on each?

Comment: I want to set a different one for each documents

Comment: possible duplicate of [Change the version manually of a Document in Alfresco using OpenCmis](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15085254/change-the-version-manually-of-a-document-in-alfresco-using-opencmis)